# Use xdof with if@inlines in BI Publisher RTF template

Tags: xml, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I am trying to us `xdof` function (to use If/Else logic) with `if@inlines` (to prevent text from going to next line) and can not get the text to output on one line with this syntax. Can anyone let me know if this is not the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xdofx:if@inlines: A.DESCRSHORT = 'CNG' then 'two' else 'one' end if?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xdoxslt:ifelse(A.DESCRSHORT = 'CNG', 'two', 'one')?>
```

This doesn't add a linebreak for me, so @inlines should not be neccessary.

Syntax: `<?xdoxslt:ifelse(condition,true,false)?>`

Answer (score 0):

This one also works:

```
<?if@inlines:number(UUU_IS_SUMMARY)=1 and number(MARK_AS_COMPLETE)=1?>
Put Your Text
<?end if?>
```